# Remove lines if pattern match except if line contains string

Tags: regex

All lines in a text file should be removed if matching the pattern `xxx` unless the line contains `yyy`.

Example input (literal):

```
- 1 The first line does not contain the pattern.
- 2 The second line does contain the pattern xxx but still can't be deleted because of yyy.
- 3 The third line should be remove because it only contains xxx.
```

The desired output (literal):

```
 
- 1 The first line does not contain the pattern.
- 2 The second line does contain the pattern xxx but still can't be deleted because of yyy.
```

Comment: Are the line numbers part of the input /output?

Comment: Please post a clear sample of input/output . i.e.: "__i have this__" and  "__I need this__".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (untested)

```
 awk '!/xxx/ || /yyy/'
```

Answer (score 0):

if the line numbers are part of the input/output

```
$ awk '!/xxx/ || /yyy/ {$1=++c;print}' lines

1 This first line does not contain the pattern.
2 This second line does contain the pattern xxx but still can't be deleted because of yyy.
```

if line numbers are not needed, use @rici's solution